# How to make the code to more pythonic way

Tags: python

```
for pl in pokemon_list: 
    if pl["pokemon"] == showtype:
        result = f"stamina: {'{:.2f}'.format((pl['stamina']/statmax)*100)}% ("

        for i in range(pl["stamina"]):
            result += "*"
```

How do I convert the code above to a more pythonic way?

Comment: It looks pretty pythonic to me. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: It looks pythonic. Depends on your purpose you could use an iterator or generator for your loop. 
for the first assignation of result, you could create a lambda function (again, as Goion said, it looks pythonic but depends on what are you trying to do and the effort involved)

Comment: Hello @Goion and Juan. Thanks for your response. However, I would like to have it similar on the code below. 
return  {
                f"stamina: {'{:.2f}'.format((pl['stamina']/statmax)*100)}% ( { stamina.append('*') for i in range(12) })" for pl in pokemon_list if pl["pokemon"] == showtype 
            }

Comment: check list comprehension: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: This is barely readable. Put it in the question.

Comment: Repeated use of `+=` is inefficient, as you need to copy the old string into a new one each time. Something like `result += '*' * pl["stamina"]` would be more efficient.

Comment: I would like to somehow to convert it to a List Comprehension to shorten the code. Is that possible from the code I provided in the question?

Comment: Shorter code != Pythonic. Your code doesn't create a list so why would you use a list comprehension? This code is fine as it is

Comment: If this is working code that you're looking for general feedback on, [codereview.se] might be a better choice. Stack Overflow is mostly intended for questions where you have a specific problem you're trying solve (e.g. if you have some issue with the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, using `str.format()` inside of an f-string is not sensible. Pick one
technique or the other, depending on the situation. For readability and
maintainability, do the computations outside of the f-string. An f-string is an
awkward context for computation; but it's perfect for simple variable
interpolation. In your case, you'd probably be better off sticking to
`format()`.

Second, list comprehension is just a tool. It's not the holy grail of Python.
Select the tool only when it makes sense. One key test is whether you want
to create a list. You do not, as far as I can tell.

Your comment implies that you want to return the first matching item during the
iteration. If so, just do it. While you're at it, help your reader by using
convenience variables to reduce the visual weight of the code.

```
fmt = "stamina: '{:.2f}'% ({}"
for pl in pokemon_list: 
    if pl["pokemon"] == showtype:
        s = pl['stamina']
        return fmt.format(100 * s / statmax, '*' * s)
```

Could this be rewritten in the style of a comprehension? Yes, but it would be
less readable, even after breaking it apart into three lines of code. Avoid the
temptation to write overly fancy code like this, which will just leave your
readers scratching their heads.

```
fmt = "stamina: '{:.2f}'% ({}"
gen = (
    fmt.format(100 * pl['stamina'] / statmax, '*' * pl["stamina"])
    for pl in pokemon_list:
    if pl["pokemon"] == showtype
)
return next(gen, None)
```